# MBProgressHUD disappears unexpectedly

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

I'm facing a very typical problem while using `MBProgressHUB`. My problem is that whenever i call `[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:NO]` as soon as `[someTextField resignFirstResponder]`, the `MBProgressHUB` shows up for 1-2 seconds and disappears immediately by itself. Here is my code: - 
**AppDelegate.m**

```
 + (MBProgressHUD *)showGlobalProgressHUD {
        UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:window animated:YES];
        MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:NO];
        return hud;
    }

    + (void)dismissGlobalHUD {
        UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:window animated:NO];
    }
```

**and in ViewController.h**

```
 @interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFiled1;

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.textFiled1.delegate = self;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        // shows MBProgressHUD for 1-2 secs and disappears by itself

        // I want to dismiss manually ?
        [AppDelegate showGlobalProgressHUD]; 
        return NO;
    }

@end
```

what could be the reason?

Comment: Maybe problem with implementing it in AppDelegate. try adding that code in your local file. it should work

Comment: that solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Glad i could help :)